# mysql group by table b, inner join table a for a random

Tags: php, mysql, random, inner-join

here is my 2 tables, id for a inner join event. i want to do this thing:

in table b, there has `10 albums`, i want random get out `4 albums`. then `each album` select `one record`, the record is random position in the album.

so that i will get 4 records back `(these 4 records with no duplicate id)`, then take these 4 records for a inner join query, to get the `title` from `table a`.

here just little records just for test. in the fact, i have 300,000 records in table a and 2,000,000 records in table b.

table a

```
+-----+-------+
| id  | title | 
+-----+-------+
| 1   | a1    |
+-----+-------+
| 2   | a2    |
+-----+-------+
| 3   | a3    |
+-----+-------+
| 4   | a4    |
+-----+-------+
| 5   | a5    |
+-----+-------+
| 6   | a6    |
+-----+-------+
```

table b

```
+-----+--------+
| id  | album  | 
+-----+--------+
|  1  | album1 | 
+-----+--------+
|  2  | album1 | 
+-----+--------+
|  3  | album1 | 
+-----+--------+
|  6  | album1 | 
+-----+--------+
|  2  | album2 | 
+-----+--------+
|  3  | album2 | 
+-----+--------+
|  5  | album3 | 
+-----+--------+
|  6  | album3 | 
+-----+--------+
|  3  | album4 | 
+-----+--------+
|  2  | album5 | 
+-----+--------+
|  4  | album5 | 
+-----+--------+
|  5  | album5 | 
+-----+--------+
|  1  | album6 | 
+-----+--------+
|  3  | album6 | 
+-----+--------+
|  2  | album7 | 
+-----+--------+
|  4  | album7 | 
+-----+--------+
|  1  | album8 | 
+-----+--------+
|  5  | album8 | 
+-----+--------+
|  3  | album9 | 
+-----+--------+
|  2  | album10| 
+-----+--------+
|  5  | album10| 
+-----+--------+
```

I am not good at mysql query. In my mind I would do

```
select * from b group by album order by random() limit 0,4
```

get back 4 album, then do a inner join query (this query not correct, how to check the b.id no duplicate?)

```
select * from b inner join a on b.id = a.id where (select id from b where b.album = '".$row['album']."'  order by random() limit 1)
```

I need an easy and quicker method, the best is just use one query. many thanks.

Comment: If I'm reading that right, you'd like to pick 10 albums at random from your list of albums, then pick out one track at random from each of those 10 albums?

Comment: Put it another way, you want to randomly choose 4 tracks (which in turn allows you to select the album as well) but no two tracks can belong to same album?

Comment: @Marc B, yes, and each track with no duplicate by the id.

Comment: @Salman A, yes, no two tracks can belong to same album. I would query out the `a.title` for the random album by something like the cover detailed introduce.

Comment: If the tracks cannot belong to the same album, I'm afraid there is no simpler way than using a cursor to iterate over those 4 random albums, and performing a separate random-track-select-query on each of them.

Comment: @Irfy, if mysql is not easy, maybe could do the stuff with php array()

Comment: this covers some of the complexities of [selecting random records](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/). you may want to trade some randomness for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIR, "ORDER BY RAND()" is extremely slow solutions, especially on tables like you have (2 million+ records), so I'd recommend looking at something similar to these kind of articles first: http://www.greggdev.com/web/articles.php?id=6

So, you should know the number of records in your table before running the query and then do something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM `album` LIMIT 1 OFFSET " . rand(0,$count)
```

This will return you 1 random row a bit more efficiently, I believe.

Also, I think it's not a good idea to store album references as string in tracks table, you'd rather use a proper integer foreign key album_id referenced to albums.id. Then you can join both tables much fatser. If I were you, I'd do first:

```
ALTER TABLE `tracks` add column `album_id` int;
UPDATE `tracks` SET `album_id` = SUBSTRING(`album`,5);
```

Then, after doing this and combining with the solution above, launch something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM `album` INNER JOIN `tracks`ON `tracks`.`album_id` = `albums`.`id` LIMIT 1 OFFSET " . rand(0,$count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm neither an expert on MySQL nor on PHP, I'll try with pseudocode and generic SQL. I have renamed your tables to `albums` and `tracks` for sake of readability.

1. First fetch the four random records to your PHP application:

   ```
   select id from albums order by random() limit 4
   ```
2. Second, iterate over the resulting result set of four IDs and fetch the corresponding tracks (pseudo-php):

   ```
   foreach($album_ids as $id):
       execute_query("select id from tracks where album_id = ? order by random(), limit 1", $id)
   ```

It is not obvious to me how you match your tracks to their albums. You should have something like `tracks.album_id` as a foreign key to `albums.id`, that's how I designed my queries. You should adapt as appropriate, the underlying logic behind my solution should remain the same.